# How to get highlighted text from event

Tags: front-end, text, eventhandler, dynamic

I want to do the following:

Given a text in a Mathematica dynamic module "at runtime". If some text is selected with the cursor/mouse, after the mouse button release, get the selected text.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: How is the text presented? In a text cell printed from inside a dynamic module? Can you give an example?

Comment: The text is in an InputField in a dynamicModule.

Answer (score 2):

The following copies the selected text to the clipboard

```
DynamicModule[{},
 EventHandler[Dynamic@InputField[x], 
             {"MouseUp" :> 
              FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], "Copy"]]}, 
              PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The text is stored (upon releasing the mouse button) in the variable `val` with this code:

```
 EventHandler[
  InputField[],
  {"MouseUp" :> (val = CurrentValue["SelectionData"])},
  PassEventsDown -> True
  ]
```

It should work in other contexts as well besides `InputField`, as I noted in my comment it is not clear from your question what the context is.